# MYSQL Insert into com where not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select, sql-insert

Pessoal tenho a seguinte situação, tenho 2 tabelas, preciso inserir na tabela B dados que estão na tabela A, porém, deve-se verificar se os dados que estão na tabela A já existem na tabela B, se existir deve desconsiderar, só poderá inserir se não existir os dados.

Estou tentando com a seguinte query:

```
INSERT INTO TABELA B (
n_notif_esus_ve,
data_notificacao,
data_inicio_sintomas,
exames,
nome,
nome_mae,
sexo,
data_nasc,
idade,
raca_cor,
endereco,
bairro,
telefone,
cpf_api,
cns_api
)
SELECT
n_notificacao,
data_notificacao,
data_inicio_sintomas,
tipo_teste,
nome,
nome_mae,
sexo,
data_nasc,
idade,
raca_cor,
endereco,
bairro,
telefone,
cpf,
cns
FROM
TABELA A
WHERE
(SELECT * FROM TABELA A y
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABELA B x WHERE y.nome = x.nome AND y.data_nasc = x.data_nasc
));
```

Testei separadamente o insert e a query que contém o where not exists, separadas ambas funcionam, porém quando coloco o where not exists como condição, recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Agradeço quem puder ajudar, obg.

Comment: Você deveria comparar apenas 1 coluna dentro do `where`, alguma chave primária talvez, não sei como estão estruturadas suas tabelas.

Comment: Seu subselect está retornando todos os campos de todas as linhas da TABELA A cujo nome/data de nascimento não existam na TABELA B. Isto não é uma condição (cujo resultado seja verdadeiro ou falso).

Comment: Oi, @ThRnk, são duas tabelas que não tem relação, 1 tabela são dados que vem da API externa, e a outra é a tabela que contém os dados que são manipulados pelos usuários.

@anonimo, realmente, eu fiz uma mudança com a seguinte query que faz praticamente a mesma coisa, só que usei o distinct para evitar duplicidades: A sub query ficou assim..

 `(select distinct nome, data_nasc from tabela B
where (nome,data_nasc) not in 
(select distinct nome, data_nasc from tabela A));`

Mas o mesmo erro persiste :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUÇÃO:

A solução foi concatenar os campos no where, estava passando 2 campos, concatenei e comparei depois. Segue abaixo:

```
INSERT INTO table two (
    campos
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    campos
FROM
    table one a
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table two b 
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN (a.nome IS NOT NULL AND a.data_nasc IS NOT NULL AND a.cpf IS NOT NULL AND b.nome IS NOT NULL and b.data_nasc IS NOT NULL and b.cpf_api IS NOT NULL)
            THEN concat(a.nome, a.data_nasc, a.cpf) = concat(b.nome, b.data_nasc, b.cpf_api)
    END);
```

Answer (score -1):

Eai cara beleza?

Já me deparei com uma situação parecida, não tenho o fonte pra olhar como foi resolvido na época.. mais na parte de SQL, lembro que algo assim resolveu :

```
select if (
  exists ( select * from nota_geral where tipo_notafiscal = ? and ide_mod = 65 ), 'EXISTE', 'NÃO EXISTE'
);
```

Tente adaptar esse `if` em troca da CLÁUSULA `WHERE NOT EXISTS` ...
Se der algum problema pode postar aqui...

Espero que tenha ajudado!

Comment: E aí parceiro, de ante mão já agradeço a ajuda!! Não funciona, eu tentei adaptar o select if, mas não deu mto legal, o grande problema vem dps do primeiro WHERE q necessita q eu passe algum campo, e eu já tô passando a query direto, pq na verdade essa é a necessidade, só trazer dados que não existam na outra tabela, para assim inseri-los!

Answer (score -2):

Esse erro ocorre por causa da sua sub query que está retornando uma coluna.
Veja se uitilizando o IN resolve:
Exemplo:

WHERE NOME_CAMPO IN
(SELECT .... )

Comment: os campos eu passo dentro do select, pq são mais de um campo pra comparar se tem ou não na outra tabela, não tem como passar depois do where